# Can a complex number be prime?

Tags: complex-numbers, prime-numbers

I've been pondering over this question since a very long time. 
If a complex number can be prime then which parts of the complex number needs to be prime for the whole complex number to be prime.

Comment: You should look into Gaussian integers http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianPrime.html

Comment: If you assume, for $z=x+iy$ where $x,y$ are integers then yes!  Look up Gaussian Primes.

Comment: Look up `Gaussian primes`.

Comment: One point I don't see explicitly in the answers is the definition of a prime depends on a specific set of numbers. The set of complex numbers has no primes for the same reason reals don't - that you can divide them up infinitely - a prime must be indivisible. But there are subsets of complex numbers that have primes, e.g. integers obviously & Gaussian integers as mentioned below.

There may be other subsets with primes & it may be (beyond my knowledge) that primes in one subset will be distinct from the primes in another.

This relates to ring theory & prime ideals as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: @matthew.tuck I was also thinking about the same thing.

Comment: Actually above I meant natural numbers not integers, but the full set of integers has primes too - you have a zero, two units (1/-1) and primes (2, -2, etc). And Daniel McLaury did actually mention what I was getting at below, how you can have a prime in one set that is composite in a larger set, e.g a prime integer being a composite in the Gaussian integers. But I think this was worthwhile mentioning here conceptually without the actual algebra.

Comment: It is also worthwhile noting that what I said above about considering the set is a motivating factor for the field of abstract algebra, and much of the maths below about rings comes from that subject. That you asked this question indicates you'd likely be interested in a broad introduction to abstract algebra (starting with groups and progressing to rings) which would likely explain this and other interesting things in more detail.

Comment: @user109256 I've already asked a very similar, if not identical question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672725/complex-prime-numbers).

Comment: Gaussian primes are fun. But also check out the primes in the [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).

Comment: Going further we can ask about "prime" matrices ;) ( probably there are no such ones, however in the limited set, for example 3x3 orthogonal rational matrices they probably might be)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The notion of being "prime" is only meaningful relative to a base ring.

For instance, in the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ the number 5 is prime, whereas in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we have

$$5 = (2 + i)(2 - i) = 2^2 - i^2 = 4 - (-1) = 5$$

and in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ we have

$$5 = (\sqrt{5})^2$$

so over these rings 5 is *not* a prime number.

The definition of *prime* you're probably familiar with -- a number is prime if it is divisible only by itself and one -- doesn't even really work over the integers: for instance, 5 is divisible not only by 1 and 5, but also by -1 and -5.  So we need to formulate the definition of a prime differently, while still preserving the basic idea, to make sense of it in an arbitary ring.

Notice the following difference between primes and composites: since 5 is prime, if we have two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $ab$ is a multiple of 5, then obviously one of $a$ or $b$ has to be a multiple of 5 just by unique factorization.  On the other hand, if $ab$ is a multiple of 15, it may be the case that neither $a$ nor $b$ is a multiple of 15, because we might instead have $a$ a multiple of 3 but not 5 and $b$ a multiple of 5 and not 3. †

This gives us our definition of "prime" for a general ring: a ring element is *prime* if it is neither zero nor a unit, and moreover has the property that whenever it divides a product it must divide at least one of the factors.

There are a great many rings contained in the complex numbers, and in many of these rings there are non-real complex numbers that are primes in that ring.  However, given any number that's prime in a given ring, there's a larger ring in which it's not prime, just as we saw above that 5 is prime over the integers, but not over the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$.

In particular, since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, every nonzero element is a unit, so *nothing* is prime over the complex numbers.  (Similarly, nothing is prime over the real numbers, or the rational numbers.)  However, I reiterate that many complex numbers are prime over smaller rings: for instance, it turns out that $2 + i$ is prime over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

---

† A slightly more straightforward generalization of the definition you're used to would be to look at nonzero, nonunit elements $r$ for which we only have $r = s t$ when either $s$ or $t$ is a unit.  This actually gives a weaker notion called "irreducibility."  In Unique Factorization Domains the two notions are the same (which explains why they're the same for the integers), but in rings like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ where we do not have unique factorization you can have situations like
$$3 \cdot 3 = 9 = (2 + \sqrt{-5})(2 - \sqrt{-5})$$
Here each of $3$, $2 + \sqrt{-5}$, and $2 - \sqrt{-5}$ is irreducible, with none dividing any of the others.  We've decided that being "prime" is about unique prime factorization, so we chose a definition of "prime" under which each of the above is "irreducible" but none is "prime."

---

Note: several answers (including this one) have brought up the Gaussian integers specifically.  They're indeed an example of a subring of the complex numbers containing non-real complex numbers, but just to be clear they're in no way "the" natural example here -- they're on the same footing as all the others.

Comment: I like your answer, as it covers the fact that the notion can be generalised without going into too many abstract algebra concepts which the OP may not be familiar with, and too many specific equations. It's possible a reader is not familiar with the notation of ℤ[i] and such but I'm sure the meaning comes through anyway.

Comment: The Gaussian integers is "the" natural example in the sense that it is the smallest ring extending the integers in which -1 has a square root.

Comment: Even as someone with absolutly no background in number theory i could learn a lot from this. Great answer! (+1)

Comment: @kasperd: but why should -1 have a square root rather than -5? Or why not the smallest ring where 1 has a seventh root other than itself?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a complex number can be prime (in the traditional sense of the word). Recall that $\mathbb R \subseteq \mathbb C.$ Therefore, all numbers that you would traditionally think of as being prime are themselves complex (though not non-real). So in this case, we require of $a+bi$ that $a$ be prime (in the traditional sense) and $b=0.$

However, there is the notion of being Gaussian prime. A Gaussian prime is a Gaussian integer (a complex number $a+bi$ such that $a,b\in\mathbb Z$) satisfying one of the following:

- If $a,b\neq 0,$ then $a+bi$ is Gaussian prime iff $a^2+b^2$ is (traditionally) prime;
- If $a=0,$ then $bi$ is Gaussian prime iff $|b|$ is (traditionally) prime and $|b|\equiv 3 \pmod 4;$
- If $b=0,$ then $a$ is Gaussian prime iff $|a|$ is (traditionally) prime and $|a|\equiv 3 \pmod 4.$

Answer (score 5):

As with real numbers, you can factor any complex number $z$ as $2\times\dfrac z 2$.  For example, $31$ can be factored as $2\times\dfrac{31}2$.  However, in defining prime numbers one is not working within the set of all *real* numbers, but within the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. (And when Euclid wrote about prime numbers in the third century BC, he did not consider $1$ to be a number.)

Mathematicians sometimes work within the set $\mathbb Z= \{\ldots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, and then $(-3)\times(-2)=6$ is not considered to be a different factorization from $3\times2=6$, because you can change $3$ to $-3$ by multiplying it by a "unit", in this case by $-1$.  There are two "units" in $\mathbb Z$, namely $\pm1$, and the thing that qualifies them as "units" is that they are divisors of $1$.

Mathematicians also work with "Gaussian integers", which are complex numbers of the form $a+bi$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, i.e. $a,b$ are ordinary integers. Within the Gaussian integers, numbers that cannot be factored are "Gaussian primes".  The number $5$ is not a Gaussian prime because $5=(2+i)(2-i)$.  It is also $(1+2i)(1-2i)$, but that is not a different factorization because $1+2i$ can be reached from $2-i$ by multiplying it by a unit, namely $-i$, since $(1+2i)(-i) = 2+i$.

Comment: I've looked up the properties of  Gaussian primes here, mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianPrime.html , but it's not clear to me why numbers that satisfy those properties cannot be factored into new Gaussian integers. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @samarbarrett : I wouldn't take the present statements on the Mathworld page to be a definition, although it's phrased as if that's what it was intended to be.  A Gaussian prime is simply a Gaussian integer that cannot be factored except by pulling out one the four units, $\pm1,\pm i$ as a factor. ("Units" are divisors of $1$.) That's the definition. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

The concept of primality is extended to other systems, including the Gaussian integers, as irreducibility. An irreducible element is one which cannot be written as the product of non-unit elements; compare this with the definition of a prime.

This is similar in principle, but can have (initially) unexpected consequences. For example, the decomposition of natural numbers into primes is unique, but the decomposition of some of those same numbers into irreducible complex numbers is not!

Comment: Actually, the integer concept of "prime" splits to two different concepts - one concept being irreducible, and the other, confusingly, called prime.

Comment: If you're saying factorization in the Gaussian integers is non-unique, neither is factorization in the integers. $10=5\times 2 = -5\times -2$.

Comment: The natural numbers are not the integers. Negative numbers are not primes.

Comment: Well, but it's important to highlight the difference between the trivial sort of non-uniqueness that happens in UFDs like $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and the nontrivial sort of non-uniqueness that happens in non-UFDs like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]$.

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking of [Gaussian primes,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) $a+bi$ can be prime with neither $a$ nor $b$ prime. The simplest example is $1+i$. More complicated  is $4+15i$. Here I used the fact that if $a^2+b^2$ is an ordinary prime, then $a+bi$ is a Gaussian prime.

Answer (score 3):

The analogous concept would be to consider the Gaussian integers $g = m + ni : m,n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and say that $g$ is prime if there is no pair of Gaussian integers such that $ hk = g; |h| \neq 1; |k|\neq 1$.

So for example, in the field of Gaussian integers, $5 = (2+i)(2-i)$ is not prime.

Two caveats here:

(1) There is no simple way to tell of $g$ is prime, based on whether its real and imaginary parts are prime.

(2) The Gaussian Integers are **not** a unique factorization domain; that is, a number can have two non-trivially distinct factorizations.  The latter property is very likely the place where Fermat's "too big for the margin" proof was flawed, because there is indeed a very clever (maybe remarkable) proof of his last theorem that uses numbers of this form and assumes unique factorization.

Comment: Pretty sure the Gaussian integers *are* a unique factorization domain.  Maybe you're thinking of other field extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$, like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Comment: I'm curious to see the fake FLT proof.

Comment: @DanBrumleve: It's called "Lame's proof" (after the mathematician Gabriel Lame) and you find it easily on Google.  Some famous mathematician once stated that Fermat probably had something like Lame's proof, but in retrospect this seems unlikely -- it's more likely that he mistakenly assumed a proof based on infinite descent generalized.

Comment: I found a great [story](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/01/lams-proposed-proof.html) with appearances by Liouville and Cauchy.  Thanks Daniel.

Comment: The mathematician evoked by Daniel is *Lamé* (with an acute accent on the *e*), but this is probably a lame comment...

Comment: Some remarks on this answer: first of all, $\mathbb Z[i]$ is most definitely a PID (and if it weren't, your definition of prime would be incorrect, you currently have the definition of irreducible element), secondly Fermat definitely did not try to prove FLT using factorization over number fields, as these concepts wouldn't be developed for another century or two, and thirdly one can tell if a Gaussian integer $a + bi$ with $a, b \neq 0$ is prime simply by checking if its norm $a^2 + b^2$ is prime.

Comment: @mjqxxx, It apears to me that you are right; what I thought were in-equivalent factorizations of numbers like $125 = (2+11i)(2-11i) = (2+i)^3(2-i)^3$ are nont inequivalent -- in this example, $2\pm 11i = (2\pm i)^3$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z[i]$ has a division algorithm, so it is certainly a UFD.

Answer (score 2):

A prime is an integer $p>1$ that cannot be written as $p=ab$ where $a,b>1$ are integers. Clearly, any prime in this sense is *also* a complex number (since $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{C}$).

More abstractly, an element $p$ of a commutative ring is [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) if it is nonzero, noninvertible (i.e. not a unit), and satisfies the condition
$$
p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\text{ or }p\mid b.
$$
You can check that this is consistent with our original definition in $\mathbb{N}$.

David points out an example in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.